# How to use lazy with instance variable

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

Given the code below

```
public class classA
{
   int someid ;
   public classA( int x ) { someid = x; }

   Lazy<myType> lazymt1 = new Lazy<myType>( 
       return MyStaticClassMethod.GetFor( someid );    // problem statement - how should this be coded ?
   );

  public myType GetMyType { return lazymt1.value ; }
}
```

how do I pass the variable `someid` and code the `Func<myType>`?

UPDATE - here's what I tried so far and the results

```
Lazy<myType> lazymt1 = new Lazy<myType>( () =>  MyStaticClassMethod.GetFor( someid ) );
```

The above line doesn't compile and the red squiggly line says

> cannot convert lambda expression to LazyThreadSafetyMode because it's not a delegate type

Answer (score 4):

The simplest is probably through a lambda:

```
Lazy<myType> lazymt1 = new Lazy<myType>( 
       () => MyStaticClassMethod.GetFor( someid )
   );
```

You'll also need to initialize the `Lazy` object in the constructor to access the implicit object reference:

```
private Lazy<myType> lazymt1;

public classA()
{
    lazymt1 = new Lazy<myType>(() => MyStaticClassMethod.GetFor(someid));
}
```

Comment: @Kumar Well, you'll need to show more information about the code you're using to resolve the problem as the idea of using a lambda here isn't a problem at all.

Comment: @Kumar I saw that.  My question stands.  You have not shown enough to replicate the problem.  If `GetFor` is a method of `MyStaticClassMethod` that accepts an `int` and returns a `myType` then this will work.  If not, then that's your problem and we can't know what it is.

Comment: @Kumar Then move it into a constructor. The error you listed indicates an entirely different problem